# How does scala's array work while its implements are just throwing errors?

Tags: arrays, scala

Some Scala code looks very normally:

```
val array = Array("aaa")
array.update(0, "bbb")
println(array.toList)
```

Which prints:

```
List(bbb)
```

But until I looked the source code of `Array`:

```
final class Array[T](_length: Int) extends java.io.Serializable with java.lang.Cloneable {

  def length: Int = throw new Error()

  def apply(i: Int): T = throw new Error()

  def update(i: Int, x: T) { throw new Error() }

  override def clone(): Array[T] = throw new Error()
}
```

You can see all methods are throwing errors!

But why my code is working well?

Comment: I guess it's one of those cases like the primitives (`Int`, `Double`). The compiler presents the `Array` to you as a normal object, but it has special rules for compiling it.

Comment: The Scala compiler does much magic behind the scenes. Primitive types and arrays are simply "views" in Scala, proxied by `Int` and it's brethren and `Array`. You can ignore the source code.

Comment: Seems there is magic in the compiler. It's a pity I can't find any articles to explain how array works in scala after a quick googling

Comment: here is the link to the source code if anyone's interested. https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/Array.scala#L1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are primitive types on the `JVM`. To represent them inside the uniform type system of Scala which nominally does not distinguish between 'primitives' and other types, there is a dummy class that declares the interface of array. The actual methods of this class are never invoked but instead the corresponding methods of the primitive array type.

[More information](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/arrays.html). [For the JVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).